# Prometheus Node_Exporter missing power stats

Tags: ubuntu, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to get the power supply stats off a containerized node exporter(Run on docker with wordpress,SQL,prometheus, cadvisor & grafana). On windows(Laptop) these just seems to work off the bat, but on Mac(Laptop) & Ubuntu(Server) these stats are not exported.

When I look at /sys/class/powercap & /sys/class/power_supply these directories are empty, where as on windows they do contain a file named bat. When I look at powertop, the metrics are there, but they just aren't being logged to the files where node_exporter can scrape from.

I attached two screenshots of a ctrl + f of the power metrics from node exporter: 
[Windows Node_exporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkCgp.jpg)
[Ubuntu Server Node_exporter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3GBl.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Edit:
I added a link to the [Node Exporter Log](https://docs.google.com/document/d/12NwuX4U18vw8QpGjrkfiye3Cfx025CGfPB6CMToC1ec/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: On the linux node_exporter, do you have a node_hwmon_power_* metrics ?

Comment: Hi, No I don't.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add a [paste](https://pastebin.com/) of the ubuntu metrics ?

Comment: Yes, Sure I attached a link to a file that has the node exporter logs